# Kotlin serialization of a generic interface

Tags: kotlin

Trying kotlin 1.4.32 / serialization 1.1.0 (and kotlin 1.5.0 / serialization 1.2.0) I could not find a way to serialize the following hierarchy of classes

```
interface Range<T:Comparable<T>>

@Serializable @SerialName("range")
class SimpleRange<T:Comparable<T>>: Range<T>

@Serializable @SerialName("multirange")
class MultiRange<T:Comparable<T>>: Range<T>
```

I could serialize a `SimpleRange<Double>` (declared as a `Range<Double>`) with a SerializersModule including

```
polymorphic(Range::class) {
    subclass(SimpleRange.serializer(Double.serializer()))
}
```

But I could not find a way to configure the module in such a way that it can serialize/deserialize a `SingleRange<Double>` or a `SingleRange<Int>` or a `MultiRange<String>` or any combination I could declare in the SerializersModule.
For example if I add `subclass(SimpleRange.serializer(Int.serializer())` to the previous, I get a `SerializerAlreadyRegisteredException`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For dummy classes without generic fields this should be enough:

```kotlin
val module = SerializersModule {
    polymorphic(Range::class) {
        subclass(SimpleRange.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Comparable::class)))
        subclass(MultiRange.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Comparable::class)))
    }
}
```

But if you have a fields with type `T : Comparable<T>` in these classes, then it's more tricky. Generally, you would need to declare polymorphic serializer for `Comparable` interface too, but the problem is that you can't register "primitive types" (`String`, `Int`, `Double`, etc.) as subclasses for polymorphic serialization (limitation of kotlinx.serialization). And these types are crutial in this case.

As a workaround you may do the following:

1. Use kotlinx.serialization 1.2.0, which allows to declare contextual serializer for generic classes, so your module should become:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
val module = SerializersModule {
    contextual(Comparable::class) { it[0] } //use serializer of its first type parameter
}
```

2. Redeclare your fields of `T` type as `Comparable<T>` (essentialy it's the same in this case, but otherwise you'll get cryptic error message `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0`) and mark them with `@Contextual` annotation:

```kotlin
@Serializable
@SerialName("range")
class SimpleRange<T : Comparable<T>>(@Contextual val min: Comparable<T>, @Contextual val max: Comparable<T>) : Range<T>
```

3. Unfortunately, it's impossible to combine polymorphic and contextual serializers for generic classes directly in serializers module:

```kotlin
//Will not work due to loss of information about type parameter
polymorphic(Range::class) {
    subclass(SimpleRange.serializer(ContextualSerializer(Comparable::class)))
    subclass(MultiRange.serializer(ContextualSerializer(Comparable::class)))
}
```

So, in order to preserve type parameter information, subclass serializer should be selected manually via auxiliary function with reified type paramters:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
inline fun <reified T : Range<K>, reified K : Comparable<K>> rangeSerializer(value: T): KSerializer<T> = when (value) {
    is SimpleRange<*> -> serializer<SimpleRange<K>>()
    is MultiRange<*> -> serializer<MultiRange<K>>()
    else -> throw NotImplementedError() // still required even for sealed interfaces, KT-21908
} as KSerializer<T>
```

Usage:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
fun main() {
    val kotlinx = Json {
        serializersModule = module
    }

    val range1: SimpleRange<Int> = SimpleRange(1, 2)
    println(kotlinx.encodeToString(rangeSerializer(range1), range1)) // {"min":1,"max":2}
    val range2: SimpleRange<Double> = SimpleRange(1.0, 2.0)
    println(kotlinx.encodeToString(rangeSerializer(range2), range2)) // {"min":1.0,"max":2.0}
    val range3: Range<Double> = range2
    println(kotlinx.encodeToString(rangeSerializer(range3), range3)) // {"min":1.0,"max":2.0}
}
```

## UPDATE

**(Deserialization)**

Since we abandoned polymorphic serialization when serialized this data, there is no [class discriminator](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator) field in the resulting JSON to figure out what subclass of `Range` should be instantiated. But even if it were there, it's not enough - we need class discriminator for `Comparable` as well.

So, we need some heuristics to implement [content-based polymorphic deserialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#content-based-polymorphic-deserialization).

For the sake of these heuristics simplicity, I'd suggest to add dedicated fields for this: `type` (could be configured with [classDiscriminator](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator) property) and `comparableType` respectfully. So, serializer should be tweaked:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
inline fun <reified T : Range<K>, reified K : Comparable<K>> rangeSerializer(value: T): SerializationStrategy<T> =
    object : SerializationStrategy<T> {
        @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
        private val rangeSerializer = when (value) {
            is SimpleRange<*> -> serializer<SimpleRange<K>>()
            is MultiRange<*> -> serializer<MultiRange<K>>()
            else -> throw NotImplementedError() // still required even for sealed interfaces, KT-21908
        } as KSerializer<T>

        override val descriptor = rangeSerializer.descriptor

        override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: T) = with(encoder as JsonEncoder) {
            val jsonElement = json.encodeToJsonElement(rangeSerializer, value)
            encodeJsonElement(transformSerialize(jsonElement, json))
        }

        private fun transformSerialize(element: JsonElement, json: Json) = JsonObject(element.jsonObject.toMutableMap().also {
            val typeSerialName = value::class.findAnnotation<SerialName>()?.value ?: value::class.simpleName!!
            it[json.configuration.classDiscriminator] = JsonPrimitive(typeSerialName)
            it["comparableType"] = JsonPrimitive(K::class.simpleName)
        })
    }
```

Now, respectful polymorhic deserializer could be declared:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
object RangeDeserializer : DeserializationStrategy<Range<*>> {
    private val comparableSerializers = buildMap {
        registerSerializerFor<Int>()
        registerSerializerFor<Double>()
        registerSerializerFor<String>()
    }

    @InternalSerializationApi
    override val descriptor = buildSerialDescriptor("RangeDeserializer", PolymorphicKind.SEALED)

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): Range<*> = with(decoder as JsonDecoder) {
        val jsonObject = decodeJsonElement().jsonObject
        val deserializer = selectDeserializer(jsonObject, json)
        json.decodeFromJsonElement(deserializer, transformDeserialize(jsonObject, json))
    }

    private fun selectDeserializer(jsonObject: JsonObject, json: Json): DeserializationStrategy<out Range<*>> {
        val type = jsonObject[json.configuration.classDiscriminator]!!.jsonPrimitive.content
        val comparableType = jsonObject["comparableType"]!!.jsonPrimitive.content
        val comparableSerializer = comparableSerializers[comparableType]!!
        return when (type) {
            "range" -> SimpleRange.serializer(comparableSerializer)
            else -> MultiRange.serializer(comparableSerializer)
        }
    }

    //remove extra fields (which we introduced as heuristics for actual serializer selection) before further JSON processing to avoid requiring `ignoreUnknownKeys = true`
    private fun transformDeserialize(jsonObject: JsonObject, json: Json) = JsonObject(jsonObject.toMutableMap().also {
        it.remove(json.configuration.classDiscriminator)
        it.remove("comparableType")
    })
}

private inline fun <reified T : Comparable<T>> MutableMap<String, KSerializer<*>>.registerSerializerFor() =
        put(T::class.simpleName!!, serializer<T>())
```

Usage:

```kotlin
@ExperimentalSerializationApi
@ExperimentalStdlibApi
fun main() {
    val kotlinx = Json {
        serializersModule = module
    }
    val range1: SimpleRange<Int> = SimpleRange(1, 2)
    val encoded1 = kotlinx.encodeToString(rangeSerializer(range1), range1)
    println(encoded1) // {"min":1,"max":2,"type":"range","comparableType":"Int"}
    val range2: SimpleRange<Double> = SimpleRange(1.0, 2.0)
    val encoded2 = kotlinx.encodeToString(rangeSerializer(range2), range2)
    println(encoded2) // {"min":1.0,"max":2.0,"type":"range","comparableType":"Double"}
    val range3: Range<Double> = range2
    println(kotlinx.encodeToString(rangeSerializer(range3), range3)) // {"min":1.0,"max":2.0,"type":"range","comparableType":"Double"}

    val range1Decoded: Range<*> =
        kotlinx.decodeFromString(RangeDeserializer, encoded1) // SimpleRange(min=1, max=2)
    val range2Decoded: Range<*> =
        kotlinx.decodeFromString(RangeDeserializer, encoded2) // SimpleRange(min=1.0, max=2.0)
}
```

If you can come up with better heuristics for actual serializers selection (based solely on shape of the original JSON, without introducing extra fields), then you can retain original serializer and enjoy more concise JSON.

Comment: I tried this but get the following error when used with `SimpleRange<Double>` :  Class 'Double' is not registered for polymorphic serialization in the scope of 'Comparable'.
Mark the base class as 'sealed' or register the serializer explicitly.

Comment: A more complete description has been found [here](https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/1252/747662084)

Comment: @Mukoki, I've updated my answer with workaround for case of class with generic fields

Comment: This is a nice addition. Json strings produced are much nicer. They are so short that I doubt we can deserialize them automagically, but deserialization was not part of my question (event if I thought it was implicit), and I realize that I don't know how to deserialize json from my previous answer too. So I will valid your answer, and welcome and supplement hint about deserialization.

Comment: @Mukoki Added update about deserialization

Answer (score 1):

I finally could get a solution adding two more steps to Михаил Нафталь advice :

1/ add a `polymorphic(Comparable::class)` in the module, which throws

> Serializer for Double of kind DOUBLE cannot be serialized
> polymorphically with class discriminator

2/ add the `useArrayPolymorphism  = true` attribute in the json builder, which eliminates the previous exception.

Complete solution looks this :

```
interface Range<T:Comparable<T>>

@Serializable @SerialName("range")
class SimpleRange<T:Comparable<T>>: Range<T> {//implementation}

@Serializable @SerialName("multirange")
class MultiRange<T:Comparable<T>>: Range<T> {//implementation}

val rangeModule = SerializersModule {

    polymorphic(Comparable::class) {
        subclass(Double.serializer())
        subclass(Int.serializer())
    }

    polymorphic(Range::class) {
        subclass(SimpleRange.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Comparable::class)))
        subclass(MultiRange.serializer(PolymorphicSerializer(Comparable::class)))
    }

}

// Build a range here
val range = ...
println(Json{
            useArrayPolymorphism  = true
            serializersModule = (rangeModule)
        }.encodeToString(range1))
```

Result is not the most elegant (adding type attributes for primitives) but it works. Here is what I get (depends on the specific implementation) :

```
["range",{"min":["kotlin.Double",10.0],"max":["kotlin.Double",20.0]}]
```